# How to append new <tr> after current <tr>

Tags: jquery, html

I have following table structure.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on `<a>` I want to add new `<tr>` next to `<tr>` of which `<a>` is clicked.

So the result will be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Example:

```
$('a').bind('click', function(){
  $('<tr><td>new td</td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
});
```

If you want to create a clone use:

```
$('a').live('click', function(){
  var $this     = $(this),
      $parentTR = $this.closest('tr');

  $parentTR.clone().insertAfter($parentTR);
});
```

Example link: http://www.jsfiddle.net/7A6MQ/

Basically, you create a copy from the `tr element` (which includes child nodes) and insert that copy after that element. Therefore, you need the `.live` binding to make sure that newly created `a` elements do also invoke that click handler.

Ref.: [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: jAndy - You don't need `.live()` for your second example. Just do `.clone(true)`, and it clones all associated data as well. http://www.jsfiddle.net/7A6MQ/1/

Comment: @jAndy Any ideas how can we do achieve this without using jQuery.. like plain javascript??

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can write:

```
$('a').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr><td>new td<td></tr>');
});
```

Not so much difference but looks more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Please check and let me know if there is any issue.

```
function AddRaw(obj){
var $this     = obj;
$parentTR = $this.closest('tr');
$parentTR.clone().insertAfter($parentTR);
}
```

Comment: function RemoveRaw(obj){
 //alert(obj.parent().parent().html());
 if(obj.closest('tr')[0].rowIndex == 0){
  alert("Can not remove this raw");
 }else{
 obj.parent().parent().remove();
 }
}

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(){
  //alert("hi");
  var len = $("#dataTable tr").length;
  var data = "";
  for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
   var oneTD = $("#dataTable tr:eq("+i+")").find("td:eq(0) select").val();
   var twoTD = $("#dataTable tr:eq("+i+")").find("td:eq(1) select").val();
   data = data + oneTD + "#" + twoTD + "|";
  }
  //alert(data);
  $("#data").val(data);
 });
});

Comment: <td><input onclick="AddRaw($(this));" type="button" value="ADD"></td>
            <td><input onclick='RemoveRaw($(this));' type='button' value='REMOVE'></td>