# How to add a new TR to a dynamically created Table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a legacy project built using perl, javascript and jquery  where I have a JavaScript function which I need to alter to add an extra  html using Jquery.
This is the existing code of my function.

```js
function _buildAssignmentRow(assignment) { // assignment is just an array
  var $checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" name="assignment_ids"/>')
    .attr('data-id', assignment.course_section_id)
    .val(assignment.assignment_id)
    .addClass('checkAssignment');
  var show_assignment_desc = '<br><a id="show_description_' + assignment.assignment_id + '">Show Description</a>';

  return $('<tr id="assignment_' + assignment.assignment_id + '" class="listRow listRowShow"></tr>')
    .attr('data-complete', assignment.complete)
    .attr('data-expected-submission', assignment.roster_count)
    .attr('data-name', assignment.name)
    .attr('data-description', assignment.description)
    .append($('<td></td>').addClass('list_item_tint_off').append($checkbox))
    .append($('<td></td>', {
      title: assignment.name
    }).addClass('assignment_name nowrap').html(assignment.name.truncate(35) + show_assignment_desc))
    .append($('<td></td>', {
      title: assignment.course_code + '-' + assignment.course_section_code
    }).addClass('nowrap').html(assignment.course_code + '-' + assignment.course_section_code))
    .append($('<td></td>').addClass('align-center').html((assignment.date_assigned || '-')))
    .append($('<td></td>').addClass('align-center').html((assignment.date_due || '-')))
    .append($('<td></td>').addClass('align-center').html(assignment.assignment_status))
    .append($('<td></td>', {
        title: template.actual_expected
      }).addClass('align-center')
      .html(assignment.complete + ' / ' + assignment.roster_count));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I need to add an extra table row now in the same function. The new HTML code which needs to be included looks like this.

```js
var assignment_desc = '<tr style="display:none;" id="description_' + assignment.assignment_id + ' "><td colspan="6">' + assignment.description + '<br><a id="hide_description_' + assignment.assignment_id + ' ">Hide Description</a></td></tr>';
```

So I tried couple of approaches like.. assigning the HTML code to a variable say

`var existing_HTML = $('<tr id="assignment_' + assignment.assignment_id + '" class="listRow listRowShow"></tr>').
.
.
.html(assignment.complete + ' / ' + assignment.roster_count));
return existing_HTML + assignment_desc;`

This approach didn't work. The code in existing_HTML was getting missed out. Only the code in assignment_desc was displayed in the Front end. I am not sure Y?

Another thing is, I have a jquery on click function that should trigger on the click of the anchor tag `<a id="hide_description_' + assignment.assignment_id` and `<a id="show_description_' + assignment.assignment_id` , which is not happening as of now. I am not sure why. I have the below jquery code present in the same page. the Click action is not captured at all.
Here is the Jquery code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('a[id^="show_description_"]').on('click', function() {
    var show_desc_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    var cur_asg = show_desc_id.split('_'); //show_description_636148
    var assignment_id = cur_asg[2];
    var desc_id = 'description_' + assignment_id;
    jQuery('tr#' + desc_id).show();
    jQuery(this).hide();
  });

  jQuery('a[id^="hide_description_"]').on('click', function() {
    var show_desc_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    var cur_asg = show_desc_id.split('_'); //hide_description_636148
    var assignment_id = cur_asg[2];
    var desc_id = 'description_' + assignment_id;
    jQuery('tr#' + desc_id).hide();
    var desc_hide = 'show_description_' + assignment_id;
    jQuery('#' + desc_hide).show();
  });

});
```

This the closest question which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599874/how-to-append-new-tr-after-current-tr-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Append new table body row
var newrow = $("<tr>").appendTo("#tableid tbody");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like previous answer said, this is rather easy. 
All you need to do is something like this:

```
var myRow = $("<tr />");
var myTable = $("#myTable");
myTable.append(myRow);
```

if you need something more robust, then you need to append columns to your row and you're good to go.

This could be ported to a function like so

```
function createRows(numColumns){
    var myRow = $("<tr />");
    var myTable = $("#myTable");

    for(i=0; i<numColumns; ++i){
        myRow.append( $("<td />") );
        //some more could be done here, maybe column content?
    }

    myTable.append(myRow);
    return myRow.html(); //this will return the whole html generated by this function
}
```

Comment: This won't work in my case as I have to return the Dynamically created HTML to another Subroutine. Where can I add this above snippet. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This could easily be done by only returning myRow.html();

Comment: added some more depth to the previous example. Regards.